# workqueues in userspace(or userpace device drivers)

Tags: linux-kernel, pthreads

I'm working on device drivers(HDMI, HDCP) which had been implemented in user-space.

Now, I'm looking for similar-to-linux-workqueue functionality in user-space.

What I want:
a.) To Tie-up different work/functions on a workqueue and run it. 
b.) Able to flush the workqueue when you are shutting down your driver or resetting your driver state machine.
c.) Add delayed execution of work-items.
d.) cancel current-work item etc.

I'm familiar with Linux kernel work-queues and work structures(though not expert) and hence, my curiosity that how we can emulate similar mechanism in user-space level ?

Probably,I can write such kind of library by using Pthread APIs mixing it with some global queue.

Any idea/suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to serialize your work by creating only one thread?  Inside the kernel resources are more limited and it is expensive to create many kernel threads.  But in user space resources are more plentiful.  You should be ok creating a new thread when a new task is required.  If you need to delay then use one of the sleep functions (I.e. usleep(), nano_sleep(),etc.) inside the thread handler

Comment: No..there is no particular reason to create only "one thread". We could create many user threads..but would not it be a overkill if we  go through pthread_create_* and pthread_exit_ APIs every-time whenever any trivial(or non-trivial) interrupt/event is generated as we need to handle them? In my understanding, creating a single thread(or a pool of threads) in advance and tying up the work to these threads is rather easy and will be faster.

Comment: I haven't done the research so I'm not exactly sure how much overhead there is involved in creating a pthread, and I'm also not sure if that overhead would actually be burdensome to your application.  I'm curious though, you talk about interrupts which can only be done in kernel-space.  So do you have a kernel module that is handling that?

Comment: Yes,we have a kernel module which has a typical interrupt handler routine.Though,it just reports these interrupts as events to upstream and returns.Such device driver design is not encouraged,but that is the least of my concern for now as i'm getting events without fail ! :)

Comment: Well I think if you want to insist on staying in user-space, your stuck redesigning your own API using Pthreads, Pthread mutexes, or possibly futexes, and a custom queue data structure.  Seems to me that these are all built into the kernel already and you should port that code to the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Using an eventloop library, such as [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) or [libevent](http://libevent.org/) would get the job done.

Comment: Thanks @wkz. These libraries look interesting.